# What kind of paste do I use to form shapes to decorate a cake?

Tags: cake

What do I use to create forms and decorate a cake? Like the minions [seen here](https://www.google.com/search?q=minion+cake&tbm=isch):

[image]

Comment: Hello limalimolina, welcome to Seasoned Advice. Recipe request are strictly off-topic here. As well as asking to make something "healthier." We deal primarily with the culinary aspect of food and not with nutritions.

Comment: @Jay I think the question is really asking what kind of paste to make; the OP can't look for a fondant recipe without knowing it's called fondant.

Comment: The health issue is indeed off-topic, though, so I edited it out. If there's a specific restriction you're trying to satisfy (less sugar?) feel free to add it back in!

Answer (score 1):

Not really healthy, but you should use "Fondant" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fondant_icing)

It is used for most/all cake decoration; it shapes well, and is stable at room temperature; and you can color it.